# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the (?)

Tags: nestjs

[Nest] 10634   - 2022/09/29 下午5:38:25   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserInfoService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserInfoEntityRepository at index [0] is available in the WashCarModule context.
I do not know what is the wrong whit my code, please help me,Thank you!
The directory structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MCvz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSHJ2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtGz2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX25n.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73P9w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSeEP.png)

Comment: Next time, please paste text rather than inserting images, images are hard to read and not user friendly

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll improve it next time~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `WashCarModule`, you are missing the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserInfoEntity])` import. This import makes it possible to use `@InjectRepository(UserInfoEntity)` [as is mentioned in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern)

Comment: Thank you, it works, I should introduce CommonDomainModule in backend.module because I already used TypeormModule. forFeature method in CommonDomainModule, thank you for reminding again~I am sorry that my English level is not high, if there is any deviation, please do not mind~

Comment: Here is my new code.
In common-domain.module.ts
`@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([...entities])],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})`
In backend.module.ts
`@Module({
  imports: [CommonDomainModule, WashCarModule, UserModule],
})`